# Semantics and ambiguity of "returning" a value?

Tags: python-3.x

I was reading up on questions from a python quiz. Here is the following code and its respective question:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self._name = name
        self._health = health

    def get_health(self):
        """Return the players health."""
        ## LINE ##
```

*What is the required code for `## LINE ##` so that the method satisfies the comment?*

(a) `print(self.health)`

(b) `return self.health`

(c) `print(self._health)`

(d) `return self._health`

(e) More than one of the above is correct.

So, I'm wondering, is this question ambiguous?
If I state that a specific function's purpose is to *"return the value of x"*, could that not be interpreted as both literally employing the `return` command to give x's value and using the `print` command to display the value.

Both give the same answer at face value in the interpreter.
Of course, things are different if you attempt to manipulate it indirectly:

`get_health() * 5` yields a normal output if using `return`

`get_health() * 5` yields an error if using `print`

So should I always treat 'return something' as actually using the `return` command?
I suppose `print` and `return` would both be viable only if the function's purpose said something like *"Display the value in the python interpreter"*.

Comment: d). `return` in programming parlance means `return` (Python/C/... statement) to me (or implicit return in other languages, etc). It does not mean "return output visible to the user that is running your program". The comment is meant for programmers, not users.

Comment: Good point. I was completely oblivious to the blindingly obvious fact that python comments can only be read by someone looking at the code, hence a programmer, not a user which the parlance is conveyed for. You should probably put your comment as an answer instead.

Comment: Yeah, lots of people have that: start off a comment that easily evolves into an actual answer.

Comment: Note: I'd think that you might get better and more elaborate answers on, say, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . I just picked up this question because it has the Python(-3) tag, but it's obviously applicable much more generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is simply d): `return self._health`.

You almost answered your own question. Return in programming parlance means use of (the) `return` (Python/C/... statement, or an implicit return in other languages, etc).

The point here is that that the comment is meant for programmers, not users.
A print statement would imply something to the user running your program ("return output visible to the user"), but the user will not see or know about that comment.

And, as you already pointed out, the use of `return`ing an actual value allows constructs like `get_health() * 5`.
Going one small step further, I would expect a printing function to be called `print_health()`; but that's up to the logic of the programming standard & style that is being used.